# Linux os : Sending email using multiple attachment using python

Tags: linux, python-2.7

Could someone please help me with the below requirement. I am using below version of linux os :-

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
Python version :2.6.6

I need to send a multiple log files to an user everyday as an attachment. 
In my log directory i have multiple files with *.fix extension. I need to send all these files to user as attachment. Could you please let me know the code for it ?

FYI .. its a linux server and i am not gonna use gmail.

Appreciate your earliest help. Thanks !!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

There is a python package called `email` that helps you in sending mails.
Getting the list of `*.fix` files could be done using `glob`.

Something like this should do it:

```
from glob import glob
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()
# Fill out the needed properties of msg, like from, to, etc.
for filename in glob("*.fix"):
    fp = open(filename)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(fp.read()))
    fp.close()

    ...
```

The `msg`can then be sent using `smtplib` as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)